# How to sort the phone contacts in listview?

Tags: java, android, listview, sorting

I have created a listview based on this tutorial:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

In that link, I've implemented

13> Selecting multiple items in the ListView

My list view is working correctly. I've customized the list view by populating it with phone contacts using the following code:

```
private List<Model> getModel()        
{                  
    List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();    
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0)
    {
         while (cur.moveToNext())
         {
              String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
              String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
               if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
               {
                    // This inner cursor is for contacts that have multiple numbers.
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext())
                    {
                         list.add(get(name));
                    }
                    pCur.close();
               }
         }
    }
    cur.close();
    return list;
}
```

Now the name of the contacts are getting displayed, but they are not sorted. How do I sort this?

Kindly help!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at this declaration.

```
List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();
```

This is an `ArrayList` object, paramaterized to type `Model`. Now , in the `Model` class that you have created, you can simply use the `Comparable` interface. To do this you add:

```
implements Comparable<Model>
```

to the end of your `Model` class header.

Then you will be forced to add an implementation for a method called `compareTo`. This is simply how you're comparing things.

When you have added this implementation, you can call `Collections.sort()`, and pass it the `ArrayList` object, list. This will sort the list for you.

**A little more In depth I think**

So, the first thing to do is go to your `Model` class, which at the moment has a header that looks like this:

```
public class Model
```

What you want to do, is change it to this:

```
public class Model implements Comparable<Model>
```

**What does this mean?**

Well this means that you have agreed to provide code for the `Comparable` interface. You now need to write a method, `compareTo`, in your `Model` class. Something like:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
   // At this point, you put your comparison code in.
}
```

**Your comparison Code**

If you wanted to sort them alphabetically, you can use the `compareTo` method that exists in a `String` object. You first, need to turn `arg0` into a `String` object that you can work with:

```
String otherName = ((Member)arg0).getName();
```

Then you can simply return the value of the String `compareTo` method:

```
return otherName.compareTo(this.name);
```

Comment: I did that. For Collections.sort(list), it says "Type safety: Unchecked invocation sort(List<Model>) of the generic method sort(List<T>) of type Collections"

Comment: My question should really give you a step by step guide. Follow it closely! :)

Comment: You should be implementing Comparable<Model>, not just the raw type.

Comment: Apologies. I will amend now.

Comment: @ChrisCooney - Thanks a lot for your reply. But I think I'm missing something. When I give "implements comparable<Model>", it tells me to implement public int compareTo(Model another){} What do I give inside this method?

Comment: Look at the last part of my answer. It answers that question exactly :)

Comment: @ChrisCooney Wow. It worked. Thanks a lot! :) +1 for the detailed reply.

Answer (score 0):

Add Collections.sort(list) before return list. And check if the class Model implements Comparable. If not, you can use Collections.sort(list,comparator)

Comment: I tried that. It says "Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List<T>) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<Model>). The inferred type Model is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>>"

Comment: it's because Model don't implements Comparable. You have to implement the interface Comparable in class Model. If you can't, use the sort method with a comparator (and create this comparator)

Comment: Model does not implement Comparable. How exactly am I supposed to implement that?

Comment: Take a look at my answer! :)

Comment: You have to add 'implements Comparable' in your Model class. see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html